# Достижения неправильно загружаются из GooglePlay - Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, google-play, google-play-services

Время от времени, чаще всего после переустановки приложения, метод LoadAchievements возвращает completed = false у всех ачивок, даже у тех, что были ранее открыты. Не понимаю в чём может быть проблема.

Связано ли это с тем, что ачивки в Google Console находятся, пока что, в статусе "Готово к публикации" а не "Опубликовано"? И приложение находится на этапе тестирования

После авторизации пользователя в гугл плей запускается данный метод:

```
    public void Init()
    {
        _Platform = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance;
        Internals.Locator.AchievementManager.InitializeAchievements();
    }
```

Метод Internals.Locator.AchievementManager.InitializeAchievements() выглядит так:

```
    public void InitializeAchievements()
    {
        Debug.Log($"[AchievementManager] CHECKACHIEVEMENT");
        CloudController.CloudService.Achievements.LoadAchievements(OnLoad);
        CheckAchievements();
    }
```

В котором CloudController.CloudService.Achievements.LoadAchievements выглядит так:

```
        public void LoadAchievements(Action<(string, bool)[]> callback)
    {
        if (_IsDummy) return;
        _Platform.LoadAchievements((items) =>
                                   {
                                       if (items != null)
                                           callback?.Invoke(
                                                            items.Where(t => t != null)
                                                                 .Select(t => (t.id, t.completed))
                                                                 .ToArray());
                                   });
    }
```

И принимает колбэк OnLoad:

```
        private void OnLoad((string id, bool unlocked)[] result)
    {
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Debug.Log($"[AchievementManager] ({item.id}) = ({item.unlocked})");
            if (_Achievements[item.id] != null)
            {
                Debug.Log($"[AchievementManager]  ({item.id}) is present");
                _Achievements[item.id].unlocked = item.unlocked;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log($"[AchievementManager]  ({item.id}) is NOT present");
            }
        }
        //result.ForEach(t => _Achievements[t.id].unlocked = t.unlocked);
    }
```

Comment: Я думаю, что не связано с публикацией (должно работать, если есть надпись "доступно тестировщика"), при этом должно работать, если указаны емейлы тестировщиков